# javascript 'object object' from localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am getting an alert saying `[object] object` when I execute `showlogsf` function

```
 var fdata = {fidval, fweightval, feggslaidval, fgraineatenval, fwaterval};
 var fidval = document.getElementById('#fid');
 var fweightval = document.getElementById('#fweight');
 var feggslaidval = document.getElementById('#feggslaid');
 var fgraineatenval = document.getElementById('#fgraineaten');
 var fwaterval = document.getElementById('#fwater');
```

These are the two functions that could be triggered from button click

```
$('#submitf').click(function (){
  localStorage.setItem ("fdatak", JSON.stringify(fdata));
});

$('#showlogsf').click(function(){
  var fdataload = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fdatak"));
  alert(fdataload);
 });

});
```

Comment: try a `console.table` / `log` / `dir` ?

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(fdataload))`

Comment: I want to output the values that are saved from user inputs (which I have saved as fidval, fweightval, feggslaidval, fgraineatenval, fwaterval)

Comment: @gianlucatursi, it gives me nothing but ()

Comment: `alert(fdataload.fidval);`

Comment: @Roberrrt it returns undefined 
poor me :(

Comment: You create the `fdata` object before you define the other variables, also, I think you want to do something like this: `{fidval : fdval, fweightval : fweightval , ....}`

Comment: You don't need to use `#` with the `getElementById` function, it should be `document.getElementById('fid')` instead of `document.getElementById('#fid')`

Comment: There are (at least) three problems with the code shown: (1) You are alerting an object, so you get the default `.toString()` representation of the object which is `"[object] Object"`. (2) You create `fdata` *before* assigning values to the other variables, so all of `fdata`'s properties will have the value `undefined`. Once you fix that by moving that line to the end, you'll find problem (3) You are trying to save the DOM elements themselves, when presumably what you really want is their values.

Comment: Plus problem (4) You probably want the current values at the time the button is clicked, so you should move the first code block inside the button click handler.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing an object as an alert. the HTML displays this as [object Object]. You have to address the actual properties of this object, so:

```
$('#showlogsf').click(function(){
    var fdataload = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fdatak"));
    alert(fdataload.fidval);
    alert(fdataload.fweightval);
    alert(fdataload.feggslaidval);
    // etc etc...
});
```

**EDIT**: Seems like you're also saving the document element, rather than the value. I assume the fdataload.properties are actual values, you should either grab the raw HTML data or input value of this instead of the HTML element itself

Comment: Still gives me 'undefined' for every popup

Comment: Hi, what if I want to insert those saved data to a div? Because I put alert just to test whether it is saving or not

Comment: You'll have to convert it to a string if you wish to save the element:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866583/how-to-store-in-browser-local-storage-elements-created-by-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `fdata` is an array right?.

Try this `var fdata = [fidval, fweightval, feggslaidval, fgraineatenval, fwaterval];`

Answer (score 0):

> I edited values of array as xxx.value instead of xxx

```
var fdata =  new Array();   

$('#submitf').click(function (){

var fidval = document.getElementById('fid');
var fweightval = document.getElementById('fweight');
var feggslaidval = document.getElementById('feggslaid');
var fgraineatenval = document.getElementById('fgraineaten');
var fwaterval = document.getElementById('fwater'); 

var fdata =  [];
```

> like this

```
fdata.push (fidval.value, fweightval.value, feggslaidval.value, fgraineatenval.value, fwaterval.value);




localStorage.setItem ("fdata", JSON.stringify(fdata));


});



$('#showlogsf').click(function(){




var fdataload = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fdata'));
  document.getElementById("flogview").innerHTML = fdataload;

});
```

> Now it saves but I have another problem, why it is replacing data every time I click showlogsf button??