# How to locally store (JS) a HTML button and retrieve the button/s on page load

Tags: javascript, html, button, local-storage

I am wanting some help with this project I am working on. The part needed for this question is that the user creates a button and then can click on it to update parts of the page based on the id (created from the user input) of that button. This works.

However, I want to be able to save and retrieve these buttons using localStorage. I have worked with localStorage before, but nothing I try seems to work. Is it even possible to store HTML elements locally?

Just looking for some clarification of how I should go about this, or an example.

Thanks, Elliot.

on page load:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        let groupsLoaded = localStorage.getItem("storedGroupArray");
        $("#createdGroups").prepend(groupsLoaded);
}
```

when creating and (hopefully) storing buttons:

```
let groupArray = [];
      function addGroup() {
        let userInput = $("#groupName").val();
        if(userInput.length >= 1) {
          let newGroup = $(`<button id='${userInput}' class='createdGroupsButton'>${userInput}</button>`);
          $("#createdGroups").append(newGroup);
          groupArray.unshift(newGroup);
          let groups = localStorage.setItem("storedGroupArray", userInput);
          $("#groupName").val("");
        } else {
          alert("Please enter a group name.")
        }
      };
```

LINK TO CODE SO FAR:

https://codepen.io/elliot7-7/pen/zYvrBWy

(Ignore the task sections)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to serialise your button down to a plain text string?

Comment: You can store HTML as a string in localStorage. That's it. None of the event handlers (except those in `onclick` attributes and the like) will carry over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store in browser Local Storage elements created by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866583/how-to-store-in-browser-local-storage-elements-created-by-jquery)

Comment: That doesn't work. Are you saying its not possible? And do I need an extension to run JSON? I'm using Visual Studio Code. And @MikeBrockington, how do I serialize the button? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store an array of created group names in `localStorage`.

Later on they can be retrieved and processed as html elements with specified template.

```js
let groupArray = [];
let groupNames = [];

function addGroup() {
  let userInput = $("#groupName").val();

  if(userInput.length >= 1) {
    let newGroup = $(`<button id='${userInput}' class='createdGroupsButton'>${userInput}</button>`);
    $("#createdGroups").append(newGroup);
    groupArray.unshift(newGroup);

    groupNames = [...groupNames, userInput];
    localStorage.setItem("storedGroupArray", JSON.stringify(groupNames));

    $("#groupName").val("");

  } else {
    alert("Please enter a group name.")
  }
};
```

```js
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  let storedGroupNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedGroupArray"));

  if(storedGroupNames) {
    for(let groupName of storedGroupNames) {
      let newGroup = $(`<button id='${groupName}' class='createdGroupsButton'>${groupName}</button>`);
      $("#createdGroups").append(newGroup);
    } 

  }

}
```

Comment: I only just saw your answer. Thanks, this works perfectly!!